# Wordpress creating plugin for most viewed posts problem?

Tags: wordpress

I just want to create plugin that will when visitor(user,visitor,...) visit some post,remember what post,and to increment counter of that post,I wrote this code,but sometimes,counter is incremented,even post isn't viewed,or post with other Id is added to a table.Can someone help me with this,please.I know that there are plugins for this that I'm trying to do,but still want to write this plugin.

```
function IncrementPostCount($the_content) {
    global $post;
    global $wpdb;

    if(($post->post_status == 'publish') && (int)$post->ID) {

        if(is_single()) { // just for single post - not for page
            $postID = (int)$post->ID;

            $postTitle = urlencode($post->post_title);
            $postLink = urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID));

            $oneRow = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_postovi WHERE postAjDi='$postID'");

            if(empty ($oneRow)) {
                $postCounter = 1;
                $data_array = array(
                   'readnTimes' => $postCounter, 
                   'linkPost'=>$postLink, 
                   'TitlePost'=>$postTitle,
                   'postAjDi'=>$postID);
                $wpdb->insert('wp_najcitaniji_postovi', $data_array);                
            }
            else {
                $postCounter = intval($oneRow->readnTimes) + 1;
                $data_array = array('readnTimes' => $postCounter);
                $where_array = array('postAjDi'=>intval($oneRow->postAjDi));
                $wpdb->update('wp_postovi',$data_array,$where_array);
            }

            return $the_content;
        }
        return $the_content;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content','IncrementPostCount');
```

Sorry on my bad english,tnx in advance.

Comment: I think it's a little overkill to use custom tables - the `postmeta` table should give you ample breathing space. And have you checked out existing plugins that may well do what you're trying to achieve? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=popular

Comment: I want to write my own plugin,I dont know how postmeta table(meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value) can help me,can you be I little more specific?
Do you maybe se what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do that with the `postmeta` table.

```
function IncrementPostCount(){
  if(is_single()){
    global $wp_query;
    $count = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, 'readnTimes', true );
    $count = empty($count) ? 1 : $count + 1;
    add_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'readnTimes', $count, true) or update_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'readnTimes', $count);
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'IncrementPostCount' );
```

Also, it's better to hook it in earlier. That way, the count is only incremented once per page load (`the_content` can be fired multiple times per page, even on a single page. `template_redirect` only fires once per request). Also, if you store the data at `template_redirect`, you can use the updated view count in the template, giving your visitors an even more accurate view count.

And you don't need to worry about database tables, custom SQL, or any of that.

Comment: Sorry on my late response,I will try your code,tnx for answer.

Comment: Sorry,I didnt have time,understand now how it works with postmeta table,thank you very much,BUT still,counter is increment for some posts that are not viewed.For example,post with ID 43 is increment,and post with ID 56 is increment,but only post with ID 43 is viewed,what could be the problem?

Comment: It looks like,when page is reloaded it is also incremented and counter for previous post,not only the current post.