# Wordpress post visit count?

Tags: php, wordpress

sorry for starting another post,here is the link of my previous similar post [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067394/wordpress-creating-plugin-for-most-viewed-posts-problem).Problem is when someone visit some post,I want to record that,to increment counter for that post.But counter is also increment for previous post(always previous post).Can not find a way to solve this.

here is the code that I use :

```
function IncrementPostCount(){
  if(is_single()){
    global $wp_query;
    $count = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, 'readnTimes', true );
    $count = empty($count) ? 1 : $count + 1;
    add_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'readnTimes', $count, true) or update_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'readnTimes', $count);
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'IncrementPostCount' );
```

Can someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 1):

This function already exists in various plugins. For example the "[Post Views](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/)" plugin

Comment: I think I know where the problem is,I didnt check this function wp_is_post_revision,it gets real post ID,I will try,t u very much.

Comment: Still can't get this thing work?just added this line of code if (!wp_is_post_revision($post->ID))
            $pID = intval($post->ID);
        else
            $pID = wp_is_post_revision($post->ID);
,but still nothing :(

Comment: Can someone help me with this,still previous post counter is increment,how to avoid that?